# Uncaught run time JavaScript exception (Rhino)

Tags: javascript, combinatorics, rhino, runtimeexception

I am using the following JavaScript program to compute the Combinatorials.

```
importPackage(java.io);
importPackage(java.lang);
importPackage(java.math);
importPackage(java.util);
var r = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System['in']) )
var t = Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());
for(var i=0;i<t;i++)
{
            var c=(r.readLine()).split("\\s+");
            var n=Integer.parseInt(c[0]);
            var r=Integer.parseInt(c[1]);
            System.out.println(""+(f(n)/f(r)/f(n-r))+"\n");
}
function f(y)
{
    var s=1;
    for (var i = 2; i <= y;)
    {
        s*=i++;
    }
    return s;
}
```

If i give the following input:

```
2
45 42
48 26
```

I am getting the right output for the first case but for the second case, I'm getting this error.

```
14190

js: uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: TypeError: Cannot find function readLine in object 42.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java and JavaScript have slightly different scoping behavior.  Your problem is this line:

```
var r=Integer.parseInt(c[1]);
```

In Java, the for loop would have a different scope, but the JS scope covers the entire function, so your assignment to another `r` variable overwrites the `r` variable that stores your buffered reader.  Give one of them a different name.